# Can I adjust Git's user/permissions to allow me to keep a file owned by www-data?

Tags: wordpress, git, permissions

I have come upon an annoying issue where I have a JSON file in a git-synced directory which is read from and written to directly by a Wordpress PHP plugin. For the plugin to be able to write to the file, the file's parent directory and all files within it must be owned by the `www-data` user.

However, if I execute:

```
sudo chown -R www-data parent-directory/
```

...then when I try any Git commands, I receive errors of the following variety (depending on the action):

```
error: unable to unlink old 'parent-directory/file.json': Permission denied
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

To be able to use both the plugin and git, I have to keep `chown`ing the parent directory between my username and `www-data`.

Is there a better way? Can I make git able to use directories and files owned by `www-data`?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Git problem, but more of a generic Unix problem.  In your case, the thing you probably want to do is invoked your Git commands with `sudo -u www-data` (e.g., `sudo -u www-data git pull`).  Then all your operations will be done by the `www-data` user and you won't have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`git` doesn't store file owner at all. It writes files as whoever runs `git` command and handles limited subset of permission model (e.g. executable bit permission).

In order to solve your problem you will need to run `git` as user that should be owner of files (`www-data` in your case) or after running `git` and checking out all files run a script that will re-own them to appropriate user and move to place as that user. Ideal is to use CI/CD tool to build deployable package from git repository and then install it to your server and let packaging system to handle the permissions.